# Contexto en JavaScript

Tags: javascript, objeto, javascript-objeto

Soy nuevo en JavaScript y estoy aprendiendo a usar el contexto con `this` en javaScript. He estado probando ejemplos para entenderlo y los resultados obtenidos no son acorde a los esperados.

En el ejemplo siguiente me aprece como error "Uncaught TypeError: m is not a function at pen.js:42"

```
h = {
  d: 12,
  p: function(){
    console.log(this);
  },
  j: function(){
    h = function(){
      console.log(this);  
    }
    h();
  },
}
h.p();//object
h.j();//window
m = h.p;
m();//window
```

pero si lo hago así, no parece ningún problema

```
h = {
  d: 12,
  p: function(){
    console.log(this);
  },
  j: function(){
    console.log(this);

  },
}
h.p();//object
h.j();//window
m = h.p;
m();//window
```

como puede observarse lo único que cambia es el miembro j donde se hace uso de una función que imprime el contexto de la función.

Me ha estado costando entender el contexto pues en clases cambia la cosa y hasta donde sé en javaScript todo es un objeto entonces los resultados no son los esperados, si pudieran proporcionarme recursos donde pueda tener un conocimiento más profundo sobre el funcionamiento del contexto se los agradecería mucho. Gracias

Answer (score 1):

Sabes una vez vi un tutorial que explicaban porque sucede ese comportamiento en javascript cuando tu empiezas a anidar funciones el `this` empezará apuntar a `window` en lugar de la funcion

Comment: Se te agradece el apoyo sin embargo responder con solo enlaces se considera de baja calidad, además que parece hacerle promoción a un producto o servicio cosa que no es bien vista en las respuestas, la edite para solo dejar aquello relevante

Comment: y que tal si nos explica lo que vista con ejemplos?

Comment: Perdón, es la segunda vez que respondo aqui en StackOverflow, no sabia que existían estas reglas, mi intención no era promocinar ese curso pero debido a que el pidio un recurso, pense que sería apropiado, mis disculpas

Comment: Ese comportamiento ya lo he observado a través de pruebas. Si declaras una función en el cuerpo del script e imprimes el contexto con console.log(this) obtienes el objeto window. Pero en el ejemplo mostrado en mi pregunta pareciera que se rompe el contexto del objeto pues en la primera declaracion del objeto h al querer obtener la funcion del miembro p devuelve un undefined mientras que en el segundo ejemplo si se obtiene la funcion del miembro p.